# IntelliJ keeps switching to UTF8 (I want to set CP-1252)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cp1252

I have some projects which are encoded with Windows-1252/CP-1252 and I can't change the encoding. The problem is, no matter what I do, intelliJ will keep trying to read these files as UTF-8 unless I manually put every single file in the encoding list.

That requires a lot of time and effort, it's error-prone and it's not a solution at all. I have set the entire project and IDE encoding as CP-1252 but it keeps trying to read files as UTF-8 anyway.

I don't know what causes that. We are using Subversion to commit files and maven to compile (which uses UTF-8 to read files except for the super POM which uses CP-1252).

Any idea how to solve the problem? I gave a look at other posts but I found no real solution yet. I'm currently using the last IntelliJ version (2017.1.2)

Comment: Check 2 things : Make sure the project encoding is properly set in Intellij. Go to File > Settings > Editor > File Encodings and set the correct encoding for your project. And For maven, make sure the property `project.build.sourceEncoding` is properly set

Comment: What are the files it tries to read in UTF-8? Are they XML/HTML and override the encoding?

Comment: All the projects are set with CP1252 but it doesn't work. I don't know if I can change the poms, but they are currently set with UTF-8. Does that make IntelliJ change the encoding after a build or anything like that?

The files are java files.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out what was the problem. Maven project encoding was overriding Intellij configurations. I tried to edit the source encoding property before but it didn't work because I misspelled Cp1252. Now it seems to work.